# How to use placement or template overrides to hide part of a Part in a Content Editor?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm using Orchard 1.9.3 and have set up a couple of custom ContentTypes that mimic the standard Page type with an Autoroute and Layout Part etc.

These types of pages should never be set as the homepage so I want to hide just the `Set as home page` field of the Autoroute part but only for my custom types. I'm not sure what the most efficient way is to go about this. Can I target this field specifically in a placement file?

Comment: You cannot do this with Placement.info out of the box, but you could override the [Parts.Autoroute.Edit.cshtml](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Autoroute/Views/EditorTemplates/Parts.Autoroute.Edit.cshtml) to include your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [Parts.Autoroute.Edit.cshtml](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Autoroute/Views/EditorTemplates/Parts.Autoroute.Edit.cshtml) and include some custom logic:

```cs
@{
    var canSetAsHomePage = true;
    var myTypesToDisableHomePageFor = ["MyCustomContentType", "AnotherCustomContentType"];
    if (myTypesToDisableHomePageFor.Contains(Model.ContentType)) {
        canSetAsHomePage = false;
    }
}

// ..

@if (!Model.IsHomePage && canSetAsHomePage) {
    if (AuthorizedFor(Permissions.SetHomePage)) {
// ..
```

For this to work you also have to add an extra property to `Orchard.Autoroute.ViewModels.AutoroutePartEditViewModel`:

```cs
public class AutoroutePartEditViewModel {
    ...
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

and make sure to set it in the `Editor` method of `Orchard.Autoroute.Drivers.AutoroutePartDriver`:

```cs
var viewModel = new AutoroutePartEditViewModel {
    CurrentUrl = part.DisplayAlias,
    Settings = settings,
    ContentType = part.ContentItem.ContentType
};
```

Comment: Actually, could you help me with where exactly to put this override? It doesn't seem to be getting picked up no matter where I try to put it, Module/Views/EditorTemplates, Theme/Views/EditorTemplates, Views/Parts/Autoroute.Edit etc... Furthermore, there doesn't seem to be a reference to the ContentType in the Model, so for this to work I think I'd have to extend the driver too?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the ContentType, you'll have to inspect the `Model` variable for that. The view should be overridable from your module if you have a dependency on Orchard.Autoroutes defined in your module.txt

Comment: Okay, thank you. I didn't know module.txt affected that